# Pipe all Write-Output to the same Out-File in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

As the title suggests, how do you make it so all of the Write-Outputs - no matter where they appear - automatically append to your defined log file? That way the script will be nicer to read and it removes a tiny bit of work!

Little example below, id like to see none of the "| Out-File" if possible, yet have them still output to that file!

```
$Author = 'Max'
$Time = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss.fff"
$Title = "Illegal Software Removal"
$LogName = "Illegal_Remove_$($env:COMPUTERNAME).log"
$Log = "C:\Windows\Logs\Software" + "\" + $LogName
$RemoteLog = "\\Server\Adobe Illegal Software Removal"

Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable Time -Mode Read -Action { $global:Time = Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss.fff" } | Out-Null

If((Test-Path $Log) -eq $False){ New-Item $Log -ItemType "File" -Force | Out-Null }
                      Else { $Null }

"[$Time][Startup] $Title : Created by $Author" | Out-File $Log -Append
"[$Time][Startup] Configuring initial variables required before run..." | Out-File $Log -Append
```

EDIT: This needs to work on PS v2.0, I don't want the output to appear on screen at all only in the log. So I have the same functionality, but the script would look like so...

```
"[$Time][Startup] $Title : Created by $Author" 
"[$Time][Startup] Configuring initial variables required before run..."
```

Comment: Replace your `Out-File` with a `Tee-Object`

Comment: Could you give me an example as to how Tee-Object works? Not really used it lol... Did think there should be another way but googling wasnt finding anything (that explains why if im searching for write-output or out-file)

Comment: You literally just need to replace it. Tee-Object will write to the screen _and_ the file you specify, so when you run the script, you'll see the data on your console and it will also go to the file. You can type `Get-Help Tee-Object` for more information

Comment: You could nest all your stuff in a function let's say `Do-Stuff` and then use a single `Out-file`statement when calling your function : `Do-Stuff | Out-File $Log -append`

Comment: Hmm sounds like a faff.. Tee-object isnt going to overcome the fact i have to type this all the time. Gruntzy, a function sounds like the best bet.. but then i have things i pipe to Out-Null throughout the steps, i suppose i may have to break it into multiple functions.. That entails more work so i may aswell leave it as it is haha. Strikes me as odd you cant define a way to make all Write-Outputs to a file without having to reiterate it every line.

Comment: Actually, you could do this in a single function, but you will have to keep all your `Out-Null` statements...  it's not a perfect solution, because you have to set Out-Null on each line you don't want to be in the log file. On the other hand, you can't have a solution that guesses magically whether an instruction has to be displayed in the log file or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, one is to do the redirection at the point the script is invoked e.g.:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {c:\myscript.ps1}" > c:\myscript.log
```

Or you can use the `Start-Transcript` command to record everything (except exe output) the shell sees.  After the script is done call `Stop-Transcript`.

Comment: Ahh yes, the first one is the quickest and easiest! Completely forget about launch conditions haha. Thanks :)